# php select statement doesn't give answer

Tags: php, mysql

I used php code from tutorial and it worked fine. But when I am rewriting it to me it gives me null.  This code gives me what I want I mean it gives data in JSON format:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
```

But this code even it looks identically doesn't work it gives null:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT username, firstname, lastname, email, phone1, skype, city, description 
FROM mdl_user WHERE username LIKE'".$_REQUEST['usern']."'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
```

If I don't use $_REQUEST['usern'] and am getting data in JSON. But I need to use request to search specific data. So where could be the problem. Because I trustfully don't understand. It looks the same to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a pattern with `LIKE` use a `%`. Put it around or at any end, beginning or end.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['usern']);

$q=mysql_query("SELECT username, firstname, lastname, email, phone1, skype, city, description 
FROM mdl_user WHERE username LIKE '$username%'");
                                 ^
                                 |
 // You also missed this space --+
```

**Note** your query is wide open to SQL injection. Just think if someone inserts year as `'; drop table people; --`. Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to sanitize those field.

[image]

And it's better to use explicitly $_POST or $_GET,ths makes sure your data is coming from proper source.

Comment: Or better still use PDO as it will handle the escaping for you and the mysql_ family of functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

With `LIKE` you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern.

```
%   Matches any number of characters, even zero characters
_   Matches exactly one character
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are getting no result because your username is not the exact same as $_REQUEST['usern'], and that's why you're using LIKE in the first place. You should therefore place wildcard characters to tell MySQL to look for any characters (%) before or after your string, for example:

```
LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['usern']."%'
```

Keep in mind that this is inefficient and you should try to use only one % after the string (if this will work for you), or better yet, find another way to search the table.

Edit: Also as a user in the comments noted and I failed to mention, this particular code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should sanitize the variable $_REQUEST['usern'] before passing it onto the query.

Comment: While this may work, you probably don't want to keep the injection gate open, here...

Comment: But then how does year works if birthyear is int type? year value would be sent from java program.